# Unity 3D - Tags not Working

Tags: unity, c#

I have triggers that interact with planes, each individual plane has a specific tag. The problem is, that it seems to just detect all planes but one called "Middle Plane"

Here is the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtMWD.jpg) of the screen capture with the tag in the Tag Manager, and the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgjw0.jpg) of the Debug.Log comprobation that other tags are indeed detected.

The code that checks the tags when trigger enters:

```
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if (!collided) // Avoid multiple collision detections...
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Right Plane" || col.gameObject.tag == "Tri-Right Plane")
        {
            turning = true;
            collided = true;

            newAngle = Quaternion.Angle (this.transform.rotation, col.gameObject.transform.rotation);

            //Debug.Log("Local Rotation: " + newAngle);
            //Debug.Log("Global Rotation: " + Quaternion.Angle(this.transform.localRotation, col.gameObject.transform.localRotation));

            newPos = new Vector3 (col.transform.position.x, transform.position.y, col.transform.position.z); 

            this.transform.DORotate (new Vector3 (0, newAngle, 0), 1f, RotateMode.WorldAxisAdd);
            this.transform.DOMove (newPos, 0.1f); //Will correct the position relative to the z axis of both planes.
            //centerReference.transform.DORotate (new Vector3 (0, newAngle, 0), 0.5f, RotateMode.WorldAxisAdd);

            /*newPos = new Vector3 (col.transform.position.x, transform.position.y, col.transform.position.z); 

            //centerReference.transform.rotation = col.gameObject.transform.rotation;
            this.transform.rotation = col.gameObject.transform.rotation;
            this.transform.position = col.gameObject.transform.position;*/

            turning = false;
        }

        else if (col.gameObject.tag == "Left Plane" || col.gameObject.tag == "Tri-Left Plane")
        { //To avoid multiple collision detections
            turning = true;
            collided = true;

            //newAngle = new Vector3 (this.transform.eulerAngles.x, col.gameObject.transform.eulerAngles.y, this.transform.eulerAngles.z);
            //this.transform.eulerAngles(newAngle, 2 * Time.deltaTime);

            newAngle = Quaternion.Angle (this.transform.rotation, col.gameObject.transform.rotation);

            //Debug.Log("Local Rotation: " + newAngle);
            //Debug.Log("Global Rotation: " + Quaternion.Angle(this.transform.localRotation, col.gameObject.transform.localRotation));

            newPos = new Vector3 (col.transform.position.x, transform.position.y, col.transform.position.z); 

            //Debug.Log ("Yup...Angle: " + newAngle);

            this.transform.DORotate (new Vector3 (0, -newAngle, 0), 1f, RotateMode.WorldAxisAdd);
            this.transform.DOMove (newPos, 0.1f); //Will correct the position relative to the z axis of both planes.
            //centerReference.transform.DORotate (new Vector3 (0, -newAngle, 0), 0.5f, RotateMode.WorldAxisAdd);
            //centerReference.transform.DOMove (newPos, 0.1f); //Will correct the position relative to the z axis of both planes.
            //centerReference.transform.position = this.transform.position;
            //nerveImpulse.transform.DORotate (new Vector3(0, newAngle, 0), 0.5f, RotateMode.WorldAxisAdd); //Re-establish the axis, so it can rotate correctly
            //nerveImpulse.transform.DOMove(newPos, 0.1f); //Will correct the position relative to the z axis of both planes.*/

            /*newPos = new Vector3 (col.transform.position.x, transform.position.y, col.transform.position.z); 

            //centerReference.transform.rotation = col.gameObject.transform.rotation;
            this.transform.rotation = col.gameObject.transform.rotation;
            this.transform.position = col.gameObject.transform.position;*/

            turning = false;
        }

        else if (col.gameObject.tag == "Plane" || col.gameObject.tag == "Middle Plane")
        {
            turning = true;
            collided = true;

            newAngle = Quaternion.Angle (this.transform.rotation, col.gameObject.transform.rotation);
            newPos = new Vector3 (col.transform.position.x, transform.position.y, col.transform.position.z); 

            this.transform.DORotate (new Vector3 (0, newAngle, 0), 1f, RotateMode.WorldAxisAdd);
            this.transform.DOMove (newPos, 0.1f); //Will correct the position relative to the z axis of both planes.
            //centerReference.transform.DOMove (newPos, 0.1f); //Will correct the position relative to the z axis of both planes.
        }

        Debug.Log("Collided with: " + col.gameObject.tag);
    }

}
```

Interestingly, it seems that in the inspector the String Tag is boldfaced if you select the "Middle Plane" tag, I´ll comment the link of the screen capture because I don´t have reputation.

Thanks for your support and atention!

Comment: The [link](http://imgur.com/w4NNpQQ) of the boldfaced Tags text on the inspector...

Comment: You should have permission to edit your own answer and questions :)

Comment: Try adding another tag and treating it the same way as the tag "Middle Plane" to be sure it isn't the fault of the tag. Then if the problem is still there try creating a new if statement to check for just **Middle Plane** tag just above the line: `if(col.gameObject.tag == "Right Plane" || etc.`

Comment: I just made your suggestions, none of them seems to work, I tried with a new "Test Tag" tag, and and exclusive statement for it, and nothing...

Comment: The boldface text just means the tag field has been changed in this instance from the value stored on its parent prefab. If you're using this object in multiple places you'll want to double-check that they all have the tag set correctly, and haven't fallen back on the prefab's value, which appears to be something different.